# How to present multiple distributions with R?

Tags: r, histogram, simulation

I have a stochastic simulation on NetLogo in which my agents accumulate "wealth". Of course, every run gives me different outputs but with pretty much the same distribution. I use histograms to keep track of the distributions during the simulation, but I would like to produce an image that sums up what happened in the, say, 50 runs that I executed. Someone suggested to make a histogram with the means of the distributions, but I don't know how to perform that. I'm also looking for something that is not computationally huge, since I'm keeping track of also other variables during my simulations. Does anyone have a suggestion?

Thanks a lot!

Comment: If all the histograms are from the same distribution, you could fit that distribution to the data for every iteration and plot whole distributions (instead of histograms). You can also add an "average" distribution.

Comment: Funny, my immediate reaction was that this is more suitable for StackOverflow.

Comment: some (dummy-)code would be helpful so people can recreate the data

Comment: There's no real dummy code for that. Wealth is a variable owned by my agents and when I run the simulation I can see how the distribution of wealth is going through a monitor I built. At the end of the simulation, you can obtain either a list with the wealth of all the agents (which is a bit expensive to calculate for all simulations) or a 2-column table with the histogram data (1st column is X, 2nd column is how many agents have up to X units of wealth). Since the distribution at the end is roughly the same, how can I produce some image that sums up this result?